# Generalization of Mean Value Theorem to functions, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was thinking of a generalization of the mean value theorem and I think I found a simple way to generalize the MVT to differentiable functions defined such that, $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ where $I$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Here's my idea:

1) Every function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ may be decomposed into n functions using the orthogonal basis $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where $x_i$ are unit vectors.

2) So for any function $f$ on $ \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $f=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x|x_i)$ 
where $x|x_i$ is the projection of the vector $x$ onto the unit vector $x_i$.

It follows that since each since $\forall x \in I, f_i(x|x_i)$ is a function mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the usual mean value theorem applies for each $f_i$.

This means that $\exists p \in I$ such that $f'(p)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{f_i(sup(I|x_i))-f_i(inf(I|x_i))}{sup(I|x_i)-inf(I|x_i)}$

where $I|x_i$ is the projection of the set I onto the unit vector $x_i$.

Update: on second thought, the variables of the vector valued function must be linearly independent and the space they occupy must be of dimension n.

Comment: So, what exactly should we do? Are you asking whether your statements are correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering whether this method works for generalizing the MVT to functions mapping $I$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $I$ is a compact subset of $R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t the correct generalization of the Mean Value Theorem to $\mathbb R^n$-valued functions with $n>1$. Let’s look at just the $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ case. You can apply the MVT to each component $f_j$ of $f$ individually, as you’re doing, to find a $z_j$ such that $f_j(b)-f_j(a)=f_j'(z_j)(b-a)$, but the problem you run into is that there’s no guarantee that all of the $z_j$’s will be equal. David Ullrich illustrates this in his answer: the points at which $\cos t=0$ aren’t the same points at which $\sin t=0$.

There is, however, a consequence of the MVT that does generalize to $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$. If $f'(x) \le m$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then $f(b)-f(a)\le m(b-a)$. Indeed, the one-dimensional MVT is often applied in this way.

Comment: I just realized this. I think I need to add the restriction that $dim(I)=n$. So it's no longer a generalization...Perhaps I can call it an application of the MVT?

Comment: In fact, as the professor told me many many years ago, although MVT fails in this context more or less all the important corollaries still hold.

Answer (score 4):

No, the "this means" doesn't mean that. In fact MVT is false for $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$. For example, let $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, $a=0$, $b=2\pi$. Then $f(b)-f(a)=0$, but $f'(t)=(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$, so there is no $t$ with $f'(t)=0$.

Comment: Ok. But, what if I require that $dim(I)=n$? Perhaps I shouldn't use the term generalization in this case.

Comment: I can't imagine why you would think that might help. It doesn't.

Comment: Because in that case, my assumption that $f$ can be decomposed into n different functions of a single variable would hold true.

Comment: First, no it can't be so decomposed. Second, how would that help? face the facts: MVT fails for vector-valued functions.

Comment: Instead of $f(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))$ define $f(s,t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$. How is adding that $s$ supposed to make things work better?

Comment: Ok. This isn't something I have covered in a lecture yet...It's just an idea that occurred to me. I'll think about it more.

Comment: I've got to go. But, I'll think about it. Will have a response by tomorrow.

Comment: When I said $dim(I)=n$ I assumed that the variables of the vector valued function must be linearly independent and the space they occupy must be of dimension n. In your example this would mean that we would have $f(s,t)=(cos(s),sin(t))$